# Modal fade dialog does not open

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a popup by using the modal Bootstrap. Here is the modal code:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <%--<a class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Requirements</a>--%>
   <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Requirements</button>
```

Now when I try to trigger modal by button it doesn't work but it works when i use anchor tag `<a>`.

How can I make it work with button?

Comment: Pretty much works [here](http://www.bootply.com/6qadH3bRng)

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz then how come it doesnt work on my local machine??

Comment: I have no idea what's going wrong at your side, but you'll have to check if you're using the right version, console errors, any other javascript blocking it etc.

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz: all it does is just a very fast blink !!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/gd6P8/1/), please refer it. Here is the sample code for opening the modal on button click:
HTML:

```
    <div class="container">

        <h3>Modal Example</h3>

        <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
        <div>
            <a href="#myModal1" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">I am a link</a>
            <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="my_button">I am a button</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3>Standard Selectpickers</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <select class="selectpicker" data-container="body">
                    <option>Mustard</option>
                    <option>Ketchup</option>
                    <option>Relish</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

<style>
```

JS:

```
$('#my_button').click(function(){
   $('#myModal1').modal('show'); 
});
```